# JPQL query to fetch all roles of user based on user id

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql, hibernate-mapping

In my project I have many-to-many relationship between User and Role. For this reason I have also new entity `UserRole` which connects this two entities.

It looks like this:

User:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(NAME = "USERS")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private String userId;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;
   
    @OneToMany(fetch = LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles;
}
```

Role:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(NAME = "ROLES")
public class Role {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ROLE_ID")
    private String roleId;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
   
    @OneToMany(fetch = LAZY, mappedBy = "role")
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles;
}
```

UserRole:

```
@Data
@Entity
@IdClass(UserRolePK.class)
@Table(NAME = "USER_ROLES")
public class UserRole {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private String userId; 

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ROLE_ID")
    private String roleId;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Role role;
}
```

**In this scenario User can have multiple roles.**

**Question:** How to fetch User by his id (userId) with all assigned to him Roles using one query (JPQL)?

I know I can first fetch User by id, and than I can fetched separately Roles based on UserRole table.

But I want to do that in one query. I want to have User with List of Roles.

Comment: Do you really need the intermediate table `UserRole` for this actually a ManyToMany relationship between `User` and `Role`? You also have a problem with mapping: you use the same `mappedBy = "user"` for the `User.userRoles` and `Role.userRoles`.

Comment: @SternK Unfortunately I need this table, it was created in database by someone else and I can't change it. I wil fix my mapping thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to correct your mapping in the following way:

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table(NAME = "USERS")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private String userId;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;
   
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "USER_ROLES",
              joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID"),
              inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID"))
    private Set<Role> roles;
}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(NAME = "ROLES")
public class Role {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ROLE_ID")
    private String roleId;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
   
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<User> users;
}
```

This correction will not affect the database schema only hibernate mapping.
Then you will be able to do as suggested in the *Andronicus* answer:

```java
@Query(
    "select u " +
    "from User u " +
    "left join fetch u.roles "+
    "where u.userId = :id "
)
List<User> getUsersWithFetchedRoles(@Param("id") String id)
```

If you stay with your current mapping you will not be able to fetch more than one association at a time as it is explained in [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-multiplebagfetchexception/) article.

Additional details related to the `@ManyToMany` association see in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `fetch` keyword:

```
@Query(
    "select u " +
    "from User u " +
    "left join fetch u.userRoles "+
    "where u.userId = :id "
)
List<User> getUsersByIdAndRoles(@Param("id") String id)
```

Comment: but I want to fetch User and List of his Roles only based on userId

Comment: In this case I will have User with List of UserRoles, but I dont have access to Roles because I set this collection to be fetched as Lazy.

Comment: @Rocky3582 You will have the access. That's what `fetch` stands for...

Comment: This query will fetch User with list of UserRoles. In UserRoles I have access to only roleId, but I want to have access to the name of role which is in Role object. Using this query I don't have access to Role object, because it throws LazyInitException